# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_create_channel'

Tags: python, бот, discord

```
import disnake
from disnake.ext import commands
from config_file import settings

class CreateCommand(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot: commands.Bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.slash_command(pass_context=True)
    async def createroom(self, ctx):
     overwrites = {
    }

    await disnake.Guild.create_text_channel(self, name='secret', overwrites=overwrites)
    await ctx.send('Канал создан')

def setup(bot: commands.Bot):
    bot.add_cog(CreateCommand(bot))
```

Кусок кода между `class` и `def setup` я взял с сайта disnake API и чуть его отредактировал, чтобы на его основе сделать создание голосового канала после ввода команды. Но при запуске выдает ошибку

> AttributeError: 'CreateCommand' object has no attribute '_create_channel'

Пробовал менять на `class CreateCommand(commands.Cog, disnake.Guild._create_channel):`, но в этом случае вылазила ошибка

> metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases

Заранее буду благодарен за помощь

Answer (score 1):

Первым делом стоит сказать, что название класса никак не влияет на последующие команды и задается пользователем для удобства:

```py
class ClassName(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot: commands.Bot):
        self.bot = bot
```

> В его название можно написать всё что угодно.

Теперь к командам:

```py
    @commands.slash_command(pass_context=True)
    async def commandname(self, ctx):
```

Здесь всё так же. Название команды не имеет значения. Название будет использоваться при вызове команды, например, через префикс "**+**":

> +commandname

Сама ошибка возникает из-за того, что Вы обращаетесь к модулю **disnake.guild**, что невозможно. Для обращения к гильдии в которой Вы хотите создать канал, Вы должны использовать переменную в которой содержится наше сообщение. Это будет переменная **ctx**:

> Кстати, она тоже может быть с любым названием.

```py
    @commands.slash_command(pass_context=True)
    async def commandname(self, ctx):
        overwrites = {
                      }
        await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(self, name='secret', overwrites=overwrites)
        await ctx.send('Канал создан')
```